# In capl using canoe test node,which function can we use to get the first PDU from an Ipadress

Tags: capl, canoe

I am writting a capl code to automate startup time measurement of aurix controller.i want to measure the first PDU send by giving the ipadress of aurix(as i have aurix and orin together in my system)

I tried testwaitforPdu and took timestamp,but it is inaccurate as the PDU can be from orin or aurix

Comment: Just check the IP address on the PDU and if it is not the correct one, wait again for the next PDU?